# Filter Data of foreign key

Tags: python, django

I want to make a button that filter product on category 
I added productatrubuut cause I need colours, size, ect. 
**How do I get the data of category from a Foreign in foreign key? in views.py**

Get **ProductAtribute** -> **Product** ...... I know how to do

 i Like tha get **ProductAtribuut** -> **Product** -> **Categorie**.

**Models.py**

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=150,db_index=True)
    #
    #

class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #
    #

class ProductAtribuut(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='gerechten/')
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #
    #
```

I can't get category by using this.

**Views.py**

```
product = productatribuut.filter(categorie=categorie))
return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {product})
```

If someone know please give me an example how I can do it. Thanks in advance. Really appreciate it. <3

Answer (score 0):

you could do soemthing like:

```
def function_name(request, category_id): # it could be category_id,or id, or slug if using slug depend on what you have and urls
    categorie= Categorie.objects.get(id=category_id)
    product = Product.filter(categorie=categorie) #updated
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {'product':product})
```

because the foreign key is between category and product,
But,if you want to get the category directly form ProductAtribuut you have to pass through Product:

```
def function_name(request, category_id):
    categorie= Categorie.objects.get(id=category_id)
    productattr = ProductAtribuut.filter(product__categorie=categorie)  #updated
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {'productattr':productattr})
```

Comment: i have tryed that and responded of Cannot resolve keyword 'categorie' into field. Choices are: .. , .. , ..

Comment: great! tha means it actually know what you are trying to do, what are the  Choices are: .. , .. , .. –

Comment: Every column of the Table Product atribuut
afbeelding, groente, groente_id, id, prijs, product, product_id, vlees, vlees_id, zichtbaar

Comment: Its is going in to The Atrubuut class, but how do I get in from ProductAtrubuut -> Product -> categorie ?

Comment: My bad, i confused your models, sorry, i updated the answer

Comment: maybe like this.... in vieuws.py i like to get the category of a product.

ProductAtribute -> product(FK) 
Product -> Cagetory(FK)
Category -> Name

I know how I go into Product, but dont know how get in Category from Product atribute.

Like This ProductAtribute -> Product -> Category?

Comment: im srry for confusion. im bad at explaining things